Proof using Converse of Thales Theorem for isosceles right-angled triangle
Let $ABC$ an isosceles right-angled triangle with the right angle at $C$. Suppose that the points $D$ and $E$ lie outside the triangle on the half-line $AC$ and $CB$, respectively (see picture).

Let assume that lines $CD$ and $CE$ have equal length.
I want to deduce from this assumption that the lines $AE$ and $BD$ intersect at right angles using converse of Thales theorem (which namely says that the center of the circumference of a right triangle is always at the center of the hypotenuse.)
The thickly marked part is the crucial part of my question, I don't want just to know how to prove it somehow but precisely how to prove it applying the converse of Thales theorem. Note, it's easy to prove it using alternatively similarity of triangles $ACE$ and $CDB$ (and finally $BES$), but the point is that I not see how to argue using Thales.
Namely, how to see assuming $CD$ and $CE$ have equal length that the circumcircle triangle $DES$ has its center in the middle point of $DE$. How does converse of Thales imply this?
source: a former german regional contest exercise. There are hinted three strategies: Via similar triangles ( ...as I sketched above), via orthocenter (...compare with GReyes' answer below) und via converse of Thales, which I try to understand.
More concretely the hint on Thales strategy tells (tanslated from original wording in hints):

To show that there (at $S$) we have an right-angle, we can use the converse of Thales thm. The center of circle through $S$ should subdivide the site $DE$ in half.

But how can I check here that the circumcircle of $DES$ has its center in the middle of $DE$? That's the part I not got.

Think I see how to apply the suggested strategy using converse of Thales: We consider the circumcircle of triangle $CES$ (...and not of $DES$ as I wrongly conjectured above) and conclude using congruence that the angles $CES$ and $CDS$ subtending $CS$ are equal and therefore $D$ lies also on this circuscircle of $CES$, so now we can apply converse of Thales to $DEC$ and we win

It is not clear what you want, but here is a simple proof: observe that $\angle ADF=\angle DAF=\pi/4$ and therefore $\angle AFD$ is right. So $AF$ is an altitude. Obviously $EC$ is an altitude. Therefore $B$ is the orthocenter and $DS$ is the third altitude, proving the result.

that's precisely the argument they elaborated in the solution presented at the linked page using orthocenter (they called it "strategy 3"). But that's not what I was asking for. I asked explicitly how to prove the claim that $AB$ and $AE$ intersect in right angle using the converse of Thales theorem. (ie "strategy 1"). That's exactly my concern: Not how to prove it somehow, but how to prove it by means of converse of Thales. This is precisely my concern, since I cannot figure out how converse of Thales can be applied here.

maybe I see why my concern wasn't clear phrased above, sorry of causing confusion, I missed above the "don't" in 3rd paragraph, have rectified it now above. Does my concern now becomes a bit clearer?
